# Multiple filtering condition in Pyspark dataframe with not equal to condition

Tags: pyspark

I'm new to pyspark. I'm running pyspark in data bricks version 7.4 including Apache spark version 3.0.1. I'm trying to filter my pyspark dataframe using not equal to condition.Here is a sample of my pyspakrk dataframe

```
--------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+------ ------------+
|      Date|              Open|              High|               Low|             Close|   Volume|         
Adj Close|
+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+--- 
---------------+
|2010-01-04|        213.429998|        214.499996|212.38000099999996|        214.009998|123432400|         
27.727039|
|2010-01-05|        214.599998|        215.589994|        213.249994|        
214.379993|150476200|27.774976000000002|
|2010-01-06|        214.379993|            215.23|        210.750004|        
210.969995|138040000|27.333178000000004|
|2010-01-07|            211.75|        212.000006|        209.050005|            210.58|119282800|          
27.28265|
|2010-01-08|        210.299994|        212.000006|209.06000500000002|211.98000499999998|111902700|         
27.464034|
|2010-01-11|212.79999700000002|        213.000002|        208.450005|210.11000299999998|115557400|         
27.221758|
|2010-01-12|209.18999499999998|209.76999500000002|        206.419998|        207.720001|148614900|          
26.91211|
```

I'm trying to filter my dataframe  where Close less than 500 & Open is not less than 500. So I used following code

```
df.filter((df['Close']<500) ~(df['Open']<500)).show()
```

But I'm getting error `invalid syntax` and it's pointing to not equal to operator. Is there a different not equal to operator in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing '&' operator:

```
df.filter((df['Close']<500) & ~(df['Open']<500)).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer said, you forgot the bitwise AND operator `&` to combine both conditions. Note that you cannot use the Python `and` operator because only the `&` operator is overloaded for use with Pyspark column objects:

```
df.filter((df['Close'] < 500) & ~(df['Open'] < 500)).show()
```

Alternatively, you can use a Spark SQL string inside the `filter`, which makes the syntax more readable:

```
df.filter('Close < 500 and not Open < 500').show()
```